# Scroll View doesn't scroll in layout weights

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, scrollview

I want to build a UI with responsive design, so I use layout weights. It seems like ScrollView won't scroll with weights. I've tried using ScrollView without weights and the scrolling works fine. I wonder if there's a way to use ScrollView with weights. Here's my code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:background="@color/colorAccent"
               android:layout_weight="0.3"/>

            <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
               android:layout_weight="0.7">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:text="Last Button"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nested weights are bad for performance. But if you badly need this, You need to remove fixed height of buttons and need to set weight as per weightsum and height should be 0. Make changes as below -

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:weightSum="5">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Last Button"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```